# WMIC process list bug?

Tags: windows, command-line

i recently found that wmic (windows management intrumentation command-line) existed :D, which is far better w/ more options than the regular "tasklist" in cmd that saves me time.

But i found a problem when exporting to .txt, is this: [image: ]()] supposed to be that way? Because the first two letters of each line, are in the final part of each line... like here: [image: ](http://i.imgur.com/BCQ8iOr.png)].. is this a known "glitch/bug"? i couldn't find anything online that demonstrated this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no problems with your files. You have a problem with notepad. There is a limit of 1024 characters in the length of the line. The 1025th character and following are moved to next line.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't have any editor installed to test at the time, didn't know about the 1024th characters limit, with notepad++ it works perfectly, thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest your problem is related to the fact that `WMIC` outputs unicode. I'd suggest piping the output through `MORE`.

I use `[Editplus](http://www.editplus.com/) as an editor which appears to accept a unicode file quite happily. I'd suggest your editor isn't quite up to snuff.

`MORE` is a supplied utility - try `more /?` from the prompt for more info.

Processing your `WMIC` output through `more` is

```
wmic whatever | more >textfile
```

you might also try

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic whatever') do >>textfile echo(%%a
```

(as a batch line - reduce `%%` to `%` to use from the prompt)

Notepad is a wannabe WP, wannabe editor. Tries to do both and does neither particularly well. Often gives problems in batch work. Since it's a supplied utility, there's no incentive to improve it - Microsoft simply doesn't have the funds.

Hence the availability of software from other vendors to do the task required.

Comment: Through More? What is that?
btw, my editor is notepad... It used to say when it cannot support the format it's in, but it doesn't say anything, just displays that, even when i copy the wmic process list directly to the clipboard and paste there.